# Invalidate ASP.NET Identity 2.0 login without removing the application cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

***Background***

The application I'm working on is running on several different domains, all sharing the same database and IIS process. The user may switch between these domains by clicking a link, and should remain logged in when doing so. To accomplish this, when the switch domain link is clicked I create an entry in the database which contains the current value of the Identity 2 application cookie (named `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` by default). The user is then redirected to the new domain, where the value of the cookie is pulled from the database and set on that domain.

This technique is working, but the problem is that logging out on one domain doesn't log the user out on the other domains because the cookie only gets cleared from the domain that the user happens to be on when he logs out.

***Question***

*Is there a way to make the application cookie invalid upon logging out, so that when it's read on the domains where it still exists (presumably when attempting to authorize the request) it will be ignored and removed from that domain, requiring the user to log in again?*

I've tried uncommenting and setting up the `OnValidateIdentity` callback within the `CookieAuthentication` configuration. It sounds like this might be related to what I want to do but doesn't seem to do anything on its own.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
    CookieName = ApplicationCookieKey, // a string constant
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, Guid>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            getUserIdCallback: ((identity) => { return identity.GetUserId(); } ),
            regenerateIdentityCallback: async (manager, user) => await manager.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(user))
    },
});
```

`GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(User user)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one 
    // defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    // Add custom user claims here
    return userIdentity;
}
```

Comment: Is `OnValidateIdentity` working for the initial domain the user is on or not at all?

Comment: I'm not actually sure what it's supposed to do, so I couldn't say.. it just sounded like it was related to what I'm trying to do. How can I test that it's working? It does get called correctly based on the validateInterval, but it doesn't log the user out or anything. I reduced validateInterval to 5 seconds because 30 minutes would be too long if I'm using it to log the user out on all domains. I guess now I need to figure out how to make it invalid so that when the regenerateIdentityCallback method is called it logs the user out, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It uses the SecurityStamp to see if the user needs logged out or not. Otherwise it does nothing. Try to update the user's password to see if it kicks it on.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing. Adding a call to UpdateSecurityStamp from my log out action made the log out go through on the other domains as well. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll write it up later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried uncommenting and setting up the OnValidateIdentity callback
>   within the CookieAuthentication configuration. It sounds like this
>   might be related to what I want to do but doesn't seem to do anything
>   on its own.

This is only triggered when the SecurityStamp gets updated. Otherwise it does nothing. You can manually trigger it by calling `userManager.UpdateSecurityStamp()`