# Asp.Net Core logout banned user

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am banning specific user from my website and update the database fields with ban information but if they are already logged in they can still use website

I can control the database for ban information on every request but i do not want to control the database if user banned or not on every request for performance reasons.

Is there any easy way to do that?

How can i force them to logout ?

Comment: What mechanism do you use to keep the user logged in? JWT tokens?

Comment: Policy based not JWT

Comment: How have you tried to log out a user from server?

Comment: @TânNguyễn how can i logout from server? is there a way to do that like HttpContext.SignOutAsync

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098724/programmatically-logout-an-asp-net-user/3098840#3098840, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743173/invalidate-asp-net-identity-2-0-login-without-removing-the-application-cookie?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers, i did not find any way to control database,

i used cookie validator on every 20 requests to reduces db checks and if user is banned, i signout he/she

Comment: haven't you find the solution yet?