# Prevent authentication bypass via response manipulation with ASP.NET Core Identity implementation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

Web application has asp.net core identity implementation, in security testing of our application vulnerability is found-authentication bypass via response manipulation.

For eg: User1 logs in into the system with valid user credentials, and the cookie for that user is copied and the User1 logs out. User1 tries to login with incorrect password ,intercepts the request and uses User1 valid cookie to login into the system and User1 is logged in even with incorrect password.

How to destroy the cookie and invalidate the session for asp.net core identity implementation?

Asp.net Core identity,.net 5.0,asp.net core mvc

Comment: Try to use `Response.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie"); `in the Logout Post request method , but this will delete all the cookie with the key `Set-Cookie`. If not work,  you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743173/invalidate-asp-net-identity-2-0-login-without-removing-the-application-cookie) to know [SecurityStamp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.updatesecuritystampasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_UpdateSecurityStampAsync__0_) ,try updating the user's security stamp after logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SecurityStamp` Property and the `SecurityStampValidatorOptions.ValidationInterval` Property to make the logout user's cookie invalid.

1.Register `ValidationInterval` in ConfigureServices

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                
            });
```

2.Add `userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync()`in your Logout like below

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            var userid = userManager.GetUserId(User);
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userid);
            await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please see this, it worked perfectly
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/818782/prevent-authentication-bypass-via-response-manipul.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).