# Update authentication Cookie in ASP.net CORE 3

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, forms-authentication

In ASP.net CORE 3 app, I use authentication cookie without Identity. Here is the code when a user log in.

```
string securityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var userClaims = new List<Claim>()
{
  new Claim("id", id_user.ToString()),
  new Claim("securityStamp", securityStamp),
}                       
var grantMyIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, "User Identity");
var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { grantMyIdentity });
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(userPrincipal);
```

At some point, I would like to update the securityStamp of the cookie without making the user log out and log in again.
How can I do this transparently for the user?

Comment: Hi @Philiz, I think you need check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71966769/11398810).

Comment: Hi @Rena, they are doing a SignOut in your example. I don't want the user to be signed out. I would like to use it for example when the user changes its password or prevent other users to log in simultaneously with the same user account.

Comment: Hi @Philiz, Signout is also an example. You need check the answer to know what need to be added in the code.

Comment: @Rena I looked at it thanks, but I'm afraid that it does not apply to my case. I don't use Identity and therefore I don't have any "userManager" in my code. And in the answer they do a signout and a redirect.